# how to add protobuf file for topic in gcloud pubsub?

Tags: publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

In google cloud's pubsub, I can see that on creating a new topic, I have to create a new message. Can I store a protobuf file there instead of having to write the whole structure of message in key-value pairs? For the protobuf code that shall be written, I mean [this](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto). If the protobuf isnt meant to be put on the gcloud pubsub, how can I use it with grpc client?

Comment: What do you mean by "on creating a new topic, I have to create a new message" and that you want to "store a protobuf file there instead?" CreateSubscription is part of the Pub/Sub API that you need to call either via the client library, gRPC, or HTTP. What is the protobuf file you are wanting to store? Do you mean when you send a message to a topic via the Publish API?

Comment: Yes thats what I meant. Is it possible to make a protobuf based format for the message so that it becomes easy to just fill in data and also make message more strict regarding the structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to send a ProtoBuf message via the `Publish` API, you should do so by serializing it to a `ByteString` and then setting it as the message's `data` field. For example, if you are using the [Java client library](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-java) and you have a [`Publisher`](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/latest/apidocs/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/MessageReceiver.html) and `obj` of some ProtoBuf type, then you could do the following:

```
PubsubMessage message = PubsubMessage.newBuilder()
    .setData(obj.toByteString())
    .build();
ApiFuture<String> response = publisher.publish(message);
...
```

On the subscribe side, you would decode the message in your [MessageReceiver](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/latest/apidocs/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/MessageReceiver.html):

```
public void receiveMessage(PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) {
  ProtoBufMessage obj;
  try {
    obj = ProtoBufMessage.parseFrom(message.getData());
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle improperly encoded message
  }
  ...
}
```